# Oracle - combining multiple rows to columns via left join

Tags: oracle, left-join, pivot

I'm working on a mini project to learn some SQL. I am currently having some difficulty with combining multiple rows into columns.

The table I am trying to clean is

```
GroupID Product   Attribute1   Attribute 2        
100      1           blue          red
100      2           gold          blue
101      1           pink          blue
101      2           black         white
101      3           purple        grey
```

What I'm trying to produce is a table with only unique groupID's, so:

```
Group ID    Product1  pr1Attribute 1   pr1Attribute2    Product2  pr2Attribute1  pr2Attribute2 Product3  pr3Attribute1  pr3Attribute2
```

row data:

```
100 1 blue red 2 gold blue null null null
101 1 pink blue 2 black white 3 purple grey
```

I've tried the following

```
select distinct full.groupid, product1.product as product1,
    product1.attr1 as product1_attrib1, product1.attr2 as product1_attrib2,
    product2.product as product2, product2.attr1 product2_attribute1, 
    product2.attr2 product2_attribute2, product3.product as product3, 
    product3.attr1 as product3_attrib1, product3.attr2 as product1_attrib2
from tabletest full
left join tabletest product1 on (full.groupid = product1.groupid and product1.producttem = '1')
left join tabletest product2 on (full.groupid = product1.groupid and product2.producttem = '2')
left join tabletest product3 on (full.groupid = product1.groupid and product3.producttem = '3');
```

The query does not work correctly. It seems to not take into account the `AND` or duplicate in some way.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I was also wondering if there was a way of implementing this such that I did not "know" any of the product numbers (so basically I wouldn't have to hard code them in).

Comment: The word you want to search for is: PIVOT. There are more efficient methods than triple self joining.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a simple copy/paste bug: join conditions for tables product2 and product3 errorneously reference product1's id in the first part of their join criteria.

```
left join tabletest product1 on (full.groupid = product1.groupid and product1.producttem = '1')
left join tabletest product2 on (full.groupid = product2.groupid and product2.producttem = '2')
left join tabletest product3 on (full.groupid = product3.groupid and product3.producttem = '3');
```

Comment: Oh shit!. Thanks for that. I was staring at it for ages trying to figure out what was going on. Total rookie mistake. Do you know how I could go about implementing this without explicitly stating what products there are?

Comment: @user1523257 That's a lot trickier - take a look at this article ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)).